# cumulated sum after target values

Tags: python, pandas

English is not my native language so I am sorry if I am not able to express myself properly.
I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
index  bad  score
0      1    400
1      0    10
2      1    20
3      0    500
4      1    700
5      0    80
6      0    950
```

I would like to order dataframe by score (descending) and calculate the cumulated sum of bad rate (df.bad/len(df)) up to a pre-set bad rate. Example:

```
index  bad  score
0      0    10
1      1    20
2      0    80
3      1    400
4      0    500
5      1    700
6      0    950
```

My first bad rate is 0.3333. In score 80, my cumsum stop,because i hit the target (0.3333 -(df.bad/len(df)). Continuing on index 4, my second bad rate is 0.6666. In score 700, my cumsum stop, because i hit the target again.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : More examples:

More examples:

```
index  bad  score  bad_rate_row rate
0      0    10     0/1          0
1      1    20     1/2          0.5
2      0    80     1/3          0.3333
3      1    400    1/1          1
4      0    500    1/2          0.5
5      1    700    2/3          0.6666
6      0    950    0/1          0
```

Comment: The logic is still unclear, why do you reset the denominator on 3 and 6? Why do you increment the numerator on 1 and 5 and reset it on 6? What exactly is the "*target*"?

Comment: I reset my "target" when I reach the bad rate I want, with 0.3333 being my first target and 0.6666 being my second target. In index 2, i reached 0.3333, with that i start the process again from the next line, with the aim of reaching 0.6666.

Comment: Do you mean that the specific values 0.333 and 0.666 should be used as input? It really makes no sense to me...

Comment: Yes, I need to do an alignment with predefined values (input). The 0.3333 would be an input, but it could be any rate (0.2, 0.1, 0.5).

Comment: To be clear: as input you have a list of "bad rates" like [0.1, 0.4, 0.2, ...] and then you use them as you described in your examples. First you match the first, then the second, and so on. Is that correct? At first, I thought you only input 0.3333 and then you use 0.6666 because it is a multiple of 0.3333.

Comment: Yes user2246849, I have a bad rate and after the combinations I move on to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
(df
 .sort_values(by='score', ignore_index=True)
 .assign(cumbad=lambda d: d['bad'].cumsum().mul(d['bad']).div(d['bad'].sum()))
)
```

alternative:

```
(df
 .sort_values(by='score', ignore_index=True)
 .assign(cumbad=lambda d: d['bad'].where(d['bad'].eq(1))
                          .cumsum().div(d['bad'].sum()).fillna(0))
)
```

output:

```
   index  bad  score    cumbad
0      1    0     10  0.000000
1      2    1     20  0.333333
2      5    0     80  0.000000
3      0    1    400  0.666667
4      3    0    500  0.000000
5      4    1    700  1.000000
6      6    0    950  0.000000
```

Comment: I want to continue calculating the bad rate after finding my first target (0.3333). For each row I want to calculate (df.bad/i) with i being the next row. When I find my first target, I want it to start calculating the rate from the next line.

Comment: The logic is not clear, can you provide the expected output in your question?

Comment: Ok, I just edited the question